`cdk deploy --all` doesnt deploy all modified stacks
When I run cdk deploy --all to deploy all stacks, as suggested by the aws docs, I dont get the desired behavior.
If i run cdk list I get a list of all my stacks as such:
pipeline
pipeline/alpha-stage/externalcommunication (alpha-stage-externalcommunication)
pipeline/alpha-stage/vpc (alpha-stage-vpc)
pipeline/alpha-stage/intercommunication (alpha-stage-intercommunication)
pipeline/alpha-stage/storage (alpha-stage-storage)
pipeline/alpha-stage/service (alpha-stage-service)
pipeline/alpha-stage/observability (alpha-stage-observability)

if I run cdk deploy --all only the pipeline stack is created and deployed
[WARNING] aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.LaunchTemplateProps#keyName is deprecated.
  - Use `keyPair` instead - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2-readme.html#using-an-existing-ec2-key-pair
  This API will be removed in the next major release.

✨  Synthesis time: 3.02s

pipeline: deploying... [1/1]
pipeline: creating CloudFormation changeset...

 ✅  pipeline (no changes)

✨  Deployment time: 3.57s

Stack ARN:
arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:730335428471:stack/pipeline/2667ad20-0315-11ef-906b-0a89280ac13b

✨  Total time: 6.59s

I originally thought that maybe it wasnt seeing any differences in the other stacks, but when i deploy the stack manually it does see the diff and deploy it
cdk deploy pipeline/alpha-stage/externalcommunication --profile cs-dev
[WARNING] aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.LaunchTemplateProps#keyName is deprecated.
  - Use `keyPair` instead - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2-readme.html#using-an-existing-ec2-key-pair
  This API will be removed in the next major release.

✨  Synthesis time: 3.39s

alpha-stage-externalcommunication:  start: Building cba1532de344d46fde76a38d8b956373267f9fbc4a7fe247ce6caa08f05a9fde:730335428471-eu-west-1
alpha-stage-externalcommunication:  success: Built cba1532de344d46fde76a38d8b956373267f9fbc4a7fe247ce6caa08f05a9fde:730335428471-eu-west-1
alpha-stage-externalcommunication:  start: Publishing cba1532de344d46fde76a38d8b956373267f9fbc4a7fe247ce6caa08f05a9fde:730335428471-eu-west-1
alpha-stage-externalcommunication:  success: Published cba1532de344d46fde76a38d8b956373267f9fbc4a7fe247ce6caa08f05a9fde:730335428471-eu-west-1
pipeline/alpha-stage/externalcommunication (alpha-stage-externalcommunication): deploying... [1/1]
alpha-stage-externalcommunication: creating CloudFormation changeset...
[█████▊····················································] (1/10)

2:35:22 PM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack           | alpha-stage-externalcommunication
2:35:25 PM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::Route53::HostedZone 
...

So why is deploy --all not even attempting to deploy any stack other than pipeline?

This is because you're using CDK Pipelines, which is a module for deploying CDK applications with pipelines. This means that your applications stacks (under pipeline/) are deployed by your pipeline, as opposed to locally / via cdk deploy.
To deploy your stacks, simply push the code into your remote git repository and trigger the pipeline (it is triggered automatically by default).
If you want to perform an out-of-band deployment manually, you can still do so by specifying a glob pattern:
cdk deploy 'pipeline/**'
Here is the reference in the Readme:

If your application contains pipeline stacks, the cdk list command will show stack names as paths, showing where they are in the pipeline hierarchy (e.g., PipelineStack, PipelineStack/Prod, PipelineStack/Prod/MyService etc).


If you want to deploy all of them, you can use the flag --all or the wildcard * to deploy all stacks in an app. Please note that, if you have a hierarchy of stacks as described above, --all and * will only match the stacks on the top level. If you want to match all the stacks in the hierarchy, use . You can also combine these patterns. For example, if you want to deploy all stacks in the Prod stage, you can use cdk deploy PipelineStack/Prod/.

